# SSRS report not printing to a single page

Tags: reporting-services, printing, ssrs-2008, subreport, portrait

We have a requirement to bulk print a report(about 2000 pages!) and report using sub-reports, page is set up as Portrait while printing the report it does not print everything to single page and gets broken at the footer.

Can you please help

Comment: Sometimes it happens if your report is too wide (content is too wide), or you have page break in table group. I can not be sure which is it, but try first to reduce page content width (shrink your table) just to see if that's the problem.

Comment: @Nemanja Yes, there is lot of content in the report. I will also set tablix properties -> Page break options-> Keep on one page if possible

Comment: @Nemaja I found that page break (before) is used only once in the report but I have set all the tablix properties to shoe data on single page not sure if it work though...

Comment: I can tell what I do on my reports. First, in report properties, I have Page Size set to 8.5 and 11in (default for non-landscape). In interactive size I have 8.3 and 10.8in because in Margins I have 0.1in for each margin. Also, my report Content does not go wider than 8in (you can display ruler and check). Don't know does this help you.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks!